# Do cans of compressed air do anything besides scatter dirt inside?

Tags: laptop, cleaning

They often recommend to use cans of compressed air to clean laptop inside.

I'm curious if scientifically this good idea. All the spray seems to do is scatter the dust in the laptop, it doesn't actually remove it, correct? So why do they recommend?

[image: Example picture]

Isn't using a small vacuum hose cleaner better recommendation? (laptop is turned off obviously)

Comment: Small bits of dust in a PC are always to be expected. But what compressed air does is dislodged caked on chunks of dust — the PC equivalent of dust bunnies — from hard to reach areas quickly. Yes, sometimes more dust gets blown all over, but better that than having vents clogged up with caked on dust. The best solution os to use compressed air with a small vacuum cleaner: Dislodge the dust with the compressed air and suck it up with the vacuum cleaner.

Comment: Note: That picture is a bad demonstration of how to use the air can. You should blow **opposite** to the normal airflow, otherwise you're just further compressing dust bunnies into gaps they already don't fit through.

Answer (score 1):

Spraying compressed gas or using a vacuum, the results will vary based on the laptop's design, as well as what kind and amount of debris is stuck inside.  That being said, compressed air does come out with more force than a vacuum.  If you really want to clean out a laptop, you will likely need to remove the cover to expose the motherboard and the fan.  Then you can use compressed air to thoroughly clean the dust.

Comment: As in any tool, correct use is a s important as the tool itself. Have you tried opening the case and cleaning heat sinks and fans?

Answer (score 1):

Canisters of compressed air may be expensive, and I'm not advocating for them, but they do work (better than a vacuum cleaner).

It is a lot easier (and I'd argue safer) to create high pressure air stream then a vacuum - and this is probably where the benefit of pushing rather then sucking comes from.

I'm not advocating it - as its definitely not a best practice due to moisture - but I've also had success using an air compressor (once even at a petrol station) to very quickly.clean a dirty system) and indeed I do this regularly to unblocked heavily clogged [water] filters which vacuuming would do little for.   I have not tried them (yet), but you can get devices to put on an air compressor to remove the moisture.

Used correctly blowing does remove dust + but more importantly it dislodges caked on dust making it easy to wipe off and vacuum.